# Disable Auto Opening of URLs when output from a command in terminal / guake

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When working from the terminal or guake, it always auto launches my browser to open a URL when one of my command spits out a url like this:

[image]

Comment: You mean, the URL's are opened without you clicking on them? Does this happen with what you call *ubuntu terminal* wich I guess refers to `gnome-terminal` or it happens with `guake`? Please [edit] your question explaining this matters.

Comment: I guess it's `drush` (whatever that is) that opens the browser for you, not the terminal emulator.

Comment: drush is a command line command. it shouldnt be able to affect things outside of the terminal

Comment: I am removing the `guake` tag, because it is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of drush. 
To disable it, pass `--no-browser` as an argument for the drush command.

For a more permanent solution, add the following to your drushrc.php file:

`$command_specific['user-login'] = ['browser' => 0];`

The drushrc.php file is located in the ~/.drush folder. You can create it if the file is not present.

Source: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/153